# D3 : How to only load half the data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, promise

EDIT: I've added what rows looks like at the end of the post.

I've been trying to only load in the first half of the data onto a line graph but I've been having problems.

I thought taking in 'rows' (which is everything returned) and halving it would work but it returns nothing to the screen. What am I missing if you guys can see?

I have to parse the fullData to make an entirely new object instead of just referencing rows, which means once I'd cut the data in half it would actually delete the data so I couldn't load it back in later.

```
d3.csv(data, function(d) {
  return {
    month: parseDate(d.month),
    price: Number(d.price.trim().slice(1))
  };
}).then(function(rows) {
  max = d3.max(rows, function(d) {
    return d.price;
  });
  minDate = d3.min(rows, function(d) {
    return d.month;
  });
  maxDate = d3.max(rows, function(d) {
    return d.month;
  });
  let fullData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows));

  let halfData = fullData.splice(0, Math.floor(fullData.length / 2)); //this doesn't load properly

  var y = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, max])
    .range([height, 0]);

  var x = d3
    .scaleTime()
    .domain([minDate, maxDate])
    .range([0, width]);

  var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);
  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);

  var line = d3
    .line()
    .x(function(d) {
      return x(d.month);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return y(d.price);
    })
    .curve(d3.curveCardinal);

  var svg = d3
    .select(".chart")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("id", "svg")
    .attr("height", "100%")
    .attr("width", "100%");

  var chartGroup = svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "chartGroup")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + xNudge + "," + yNudge + ")");

  chartGroup
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      return line(halfData);
    });

  chartGroup
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  chartGroup
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis y")
    .call(yAxis);
});
```

What rows returns:

```
    (96) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, columns: Array(2)]
0
:
{month: Wed Jan 01 2003 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time), price: 54}
1
:
{month: Sat Feb 01 2003 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time), price: 54}
2
:
{month: Sat Mar 01 2003 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time), price: 50}
3
:
{month: Tue Apr 01 2003 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Irish Standard Time), price: 52}
4
:
{month: Thu May 01 2003 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Irish Standard Time), price: 53}
5
:
{month: Sun Jun 01 2003 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Irish Standard Time), price: 49}
6
:
{month: Tue Jul 01 2003 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Irish Standard Time), price: 51}
7
:
{month: Fri Aug 01 2003 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Irish Standard Time), price: 52}
8
:
{month: Mon Sep 01 2003 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Irish Standard Time), price: 54}
9
:
{month: Wed Oct 01 2003 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Irish Standard Time), price: 52}
10
:
{month: Sat Nov 01 2003 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time), price: 50}
```

Comment: Why are you stringifying and then parsing it again?

Comment: Some confusing things here: why would you use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(`? And are you sure you want `.splice` (which modifies `fullData`) as opposed to `.slice`?

Comment: @FrankerZ and Tom Fenech: That's a way of deep-cloning in JavaScript. We do that all the time.

Comment: @MrShedford Take care with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows))` for deep-cloning, it doesn't work with date objects (which you have).

Comment: Sure but it seems like it would make more sense to just use `slice` on the next line and work directly with rows.

Comment: If you add some sample input data to your question then it will be a lot easier to debug your issue. At the moment there are some things which look wrong but it's difficult to give you any definitive solution to your problem.

Comment: I've added some extra input now, thank you for taking your time to do this!

Comment: As @TomFenech suggests, `rows.slice(...)` makes cloning of `rows` unnecessary.

Comment: Should `max`, `minDate`, `maxDate`, not be localized?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out yesterday, this is how I did it!

```
if (completed === false) {
        rows.splice(Math.floor(rows.length / 2), rows.length);
      }
```

I have a global variable called completed that is set to false. While false it splits the data in half and only shows the first half of the data.